# Sandboxed application domain in .NET Core

Tags: security, .net-core, sandbox

I'm working on enabling security transparency model in .NET Core code (on Linux). I've discovered that just enabling APPDOMAIN_SECURITY_SANDBOXED flag during AppDomain initialization is not enough. At least my P/Invoke

```
[DllImport("/usr/lib/libc.so.6")]
private static int system(string path);
```

call hasn't blocked.
Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx as an answer. Not the best, but will try.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core [does not support AppDomains or sandboxing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/):

> Free of problematic tech. .NET Core doesn’t include certain technologies we decided to discontinue because we found them to be problematic, for instance AppDomain and sandboxing. If the scenario still makes sense for .NET Core, our plan is to have replacements. For example, AssemblyLoadContext replaces AppDomains for loading and isolating assemblies.

Comment: If .NET Core does not support sandboxing, which way you suggest to run a user code in our app?